# Examples of big datasets

Tags: bigdata, word-count

I am trying to learn some big data technologies and all examples/tutorials I come across talk about calculating the word count. Is anyone familiar with other examples or datasets that I can calculate the count of. Something a little more exciting than calculating the count of words in a book.

Comment: I see your question is still open. Would you like additional information? If you feel my answer is helpful, you could put closure to your question by marking it accepted. You are welcome to wait for more answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some examples:

- You can visit https://www.kaggle.com/datasets and download and find [City of LA Citations](https://www.kaggle.com/cityofLA/los-angeles-parking-citations) and then figure out when tickets are given the most, how much the fine was, etc.
- Get a bunch of [storm events from NCDC](https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/) and rank the state by highest tornadoes in the last 10 years and see where those same states ranked in the prior 10 years
- Visit [City of Chicago website](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2) and download crime database. Compare stats with those published in news papers
- Find Mueller's report and determine % of report that was redacted
- Get [UFO database](http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxevent.html) and find the city that has had most sighting of over 3 minutes